# download manager redirect to login by authorize action for downloading file in mvc

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use this action for downloading some files. User need to login before download these files.(it's very simple version of action code.)

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Download(long id)
    {
        //or use this code instead of filter
        if (!httpContext.IsAuthenticated())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path);
        string fileName = file.Name 
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, 
        fileName);
    }
```

when user is already logged in and tries to download file with browser, everything goes well, but if user tries to download it by some download manager software like:**IDM**
, even if user used authentication option in IDM, the login page will be download instead of file.

How can I make this action work with download managers also?

Comment: your question is not clear whether you want to continue restricting non logged in users from downloading or not?

Comment: i want to logged in user can use download managers for downloading these files

Comment: I edited you question for clarity. So you are saying that when users are authenticated then the Download manager somehow downloads the login page? It sounds like maybe you (user) is not authenticated ? Can you verify in your code that user is authenticated not just using the [Authorize] tag? Maybe you can show us your download manager code?

Comment: i use download manager software in client side then there's no code to show. and i use some other method like check session or check authorization in code like HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated but it's like user is not authenticated.

Comment: It's really hard to tell without seeing all this code, but I think your description points to the fact that somehow you are going out of context in the download process but also hitting a authorization tag which is redirecting to the login page.

Comment: when i remove the authorize filter and set a checkpoint inside the action, the check point hits but isAuthentication return false.

Comment: Exactly! You are assuming that you are Authenticated, when you are not. This can happen when your code is primarily on the front end and you are not trying to do anything on the server side for a while. your Authentication times out and when you finaly make a request from server your authentication fails.

Comment: what kind of authorization are you using? cookies? session?

Comment: @DaniDev if user try immediately after login, it fails.

Comment: @xszaboj i try both cookies and session. i use cookies for returning user too.

Comment: I think you need to get a handle on your authentication scheme. When you say:"if user try immediately after login"  How do you know for a fact that you are logged in (authenticated) in terms of your site? 
Maybe you should show us your web.config <authentication>  and <authorization> sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the download manager is trying to use basic authentication, while your application is using form based authentication.   the download manager would need to fill in the user/password login form, then submit to get a cookie to support your code.

Seems IDM uses an existing cookie from a session logged in via IE... see here:

http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/register/new_faq/sites6.html

Comment: I managed to resolve my issue by using IE 11 to connect to my account then IDM automatically used that session to download, using any other browser failed miserably. Thanks.